# Duplicate ActionBar when using fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I'm trying to build an application running on Android 4.0 with fragments and ActionBar. The issue I have is that sometimes, when using fragments, my ActionBar get duplicated as you can see below:

Home screen, everything normal:
[Home Screen][https://www.dropbox.com/s/aki8ba8ol2jaock/device-2016-02-09-182020_Home.png?dl=0]

Another screen, duplicated ActionBar:
[Shop Screen][https://www.dropbox.com/s/i03d4anw2tc97q3/device-2016-02-09-182136_Categories.png?dl=0]

Below you'll find the main_navigation.xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include 
        layout="@layout/cart_sidebar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#ffffff"

        />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Below the code managing the fragment in my class (ShopDrawerActivity) :

```
        private void displayView(Class<? extends Activity> activity) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentController fragmentController = new FragmentController();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    fragmentController = new FragmentController();
    fragmentController.setClass(activity);
    fragment = fragmentController;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();


}
```

My MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ProgressDialog pDialog;

public static final int NUM_PAGES = 3;

ViewPager mPager, vpMarqueeText;

ArrayList<Banner> banners = new ArrayList<Banner>();
TextView tvCategories;
GiloAdapter mAdapter;
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
ArrayList<ItemImage> images = new ArrayList<ItemImage>();
ArrayList<Option> options = new ArrayList<Option>();
ArrayList<OptionGroup> optionGroups = new ArrayList<OptionGroup>();

ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
ArrayList<ProductCategory> prodcats = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();
ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
ArrayList<Zone> zones = new ArrayList<Zone>();

static HTTPExecutionListener httpExecutionListener = new HTTPExecutionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(int task_number) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

DataContainer dataContainer;

Time now;

static int task_number = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.intro);

    // Added to allow makeHttpRequest anywhere in the code (without AsyncTask...) - not the best solution but working...
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    Log.d("start time" , String.valueOf(now.minute) + ":" + String.valueOf(now.second));

    dataContainer = ((DataContainer) getApplicationContext());
    tvCategories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvIntro_categoriess);

    banners = new ArrayList<Banner>();

    // Instantiating the adapter
    mAdapter = new GiloAdapter(this, banners);

    // instantiate the Views
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    vpMarqueeText = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpMarqueeText);
    vpMarqueeText.setAdapter(new MarqueeTextAdapter(this));

    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(banners.size());
    vpMarqueeText.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);

    UnderlinePageIndicator mIndicator = (UnderlinePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

    startTimerForSlides();
    startMarqueeing();

    String number = String.valueOf(new ItemsInitiator(this).itemCount());

    Date now = new Date();


    new DataGetterLocal().execute();

    // doStuff();
}

...
...
```

**EDIT:** FYI I'm using Activity and AppCompatActivity.

I already tried several solutions found on this forum but I always end up with no ActionBar, or still a duplicate one :(

I'm new to Android so please be comprehensive.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

You're right I'm extending Activity, not AppCompatActivity. I'm calling my fragment like this:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // on first time display view for first nav item
    displayView(ShopActivity.class);

}
```

Then my ShopActivity class extends AppCompatActivity:

```
public class ShopActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lvShopItems, lvCategorylist;
    ArrayList<ProductCategory> prodCats = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();

ArrayList<Item> products = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Category> categories;
    ArrayList<Item> items;
    static String slug = "0";
    GiloAdapter mAdapter;
    CategoryItemsAdapter catAdapter;
    ArrayList<Category> categories_with_slug = new ArrayList<Category>();
    ShopItemsAdapter shopItemsAdapter;
    ArrayList<Item> items_with_slug = new ArrayList<Item>();
    static ArrayList<Category> path = new ArrayList<Category>();
    HListView hlBreadCrumbs;
    SlidingMenu menuRight, menu ;
    Thread timer;
    BackPressListener backPressListener;
    public static Item curr_item;

    BreadCrumbsAdapter breadCrumbsAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.sliding_menu);

        final DataContainer dataContainer = ((DataContainer) getApplicationContext());


        menu = (SlidingMenu) findViewById(R.id.slidingmenulayout);
        menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        menu.setShadowWidth(30);
        // menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        menu.setBehindOffset(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2 - 100);
        menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        //menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);

        menu.setMenu(R.layout.category_sidebar);
        menu.showMenu();

        slug = ShopDrawerActivity.slug;
        slug="0";



        //categories = dataContainer.getCategories();
        //items = dataContainer.getItems();

        categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
        for(Category category : dataContainer.getCategories()){
            categories.add(category);
        }

        Collections.sort(categories, new SequenceComparator());

        items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for(Item item : dataContainer.getItems()){
            items.add(item);
        }
        products = items;

        Log.d("items number", String.valueOf(items.size()));

        //prodCats = dataContainer.getProdcats();

        prodCats = new ArrayList<ProductCategory>();
        for(ProductCategory prodCat : dataContainer.getProdcats()){
            prodCats.add(prodCat);
        }

        getPath(slug);

        lvShopItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShopItems);
        getItems(slug);

        shopItemsAdapter = new ShopItemsAdapter(ShopActivity.this, items_with_slug);
        lvShopItems.setAdapter(shopItemsAdapter);

        lvCategorylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCategoryItems);
        getCategories(slug);
        catAdapter = new CategoryItemsAdapter(this, categories_with_slug);
        lvCategorylist.setAdapter(catAdapter);

        lvCategorylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (pos > 1) {

                    slug = categories_with_slug.get(pos - 2).getSlug();
                    updateLists();
                }
            }
        });




        breadCrumbsAdapter = new BreadCrumbsAdapter(this, path);

        hlBreadCrumbs = (HListView) findViewById(R.id.hlShop_breadcrumb);
        hlBreadCrumbs.setAdapter(breadCrumbsAdapter);

//      hlBreadCrumbs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
//
//          @Override
//          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
//                  long arg3) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              
//              if(pos == 0){
//                  slug = "none";
//              }else{  
//                  slug = path.get(path.size() - pos).getSlug();
//              }
//              updateLists();
//              
//          }
//      });




        final Handler myHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                onDrawerBackPressed();
            }
        };

        ShopDrawerActivity.setBackPressListener(new BackPressListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Boolean back_pressed) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onDrawerBackPressed();
            }
        });

        Log.d("Category with slug 0", getCategoryWithSlug("0").getName());

    }


    public void onDrawerBackPressed() {
        if(path.size() == 0){
            finish();

        }else{
            path.remove(0);
            if(path.size() != 0){
            slug = path.get(0).getSlug();

            updateLists();
            }else{
                slug = "0";
                updateLists();
            }
        }

        Log.d("Back Pressed", "back pressed");
    }

    public void updateLists() {
        while (categories_with_slug.size() != 0) {
            categories_with_slug.remove(0);
        }

        while (items_with_slug.size() != 0) {
            items_with_slug.remove(0);
        }

        while (path.size() != 0) {
            path.remove(0);
        }

        getPath(slug);
        getCategories(slug);
        getItems(slug);


        catAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        shopItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        breadCrumbsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        hlBreadCrumbs.smoothScrollToPosition(breadCrumbsAdapter.getCount() - 1);

    }

    public void getCategories(String slug) {

        for (Category category : categories) {
            Log.d("category parent id", String.valueOf(category.getParent_id()));
            if (category.getParent_id() == Integer.parseInt(slug)) {
                categories_with_slug.add(category);
                Log.d("slug", category.getSlug());
            }
        }

        Log.d("categories with slug size", String.valueOf(categories_with_slug.size()));

    }






    public void getPath(String slug){
        String parent = slug;
        String cats = "";

        int i = 50;

        while (!parent.equals("0") && i > 0) {
            cats+= parent;

            Log.d("path", cats);
            Category category = getCategoryWithSlug(parent);
            if(!path.contains(category))
                path.add(category);

            parent = category.getParent();

            i--;

        }

        Log.d("path", cats);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuItem searchViewMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mnSearch);
        SearchView mSearchView = (SearchView) searchViewMenuItem.getActionView();
        int searchImgId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
        ImageView v = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(searchImgId);
        v.setImageResource(R.drawable.search);

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_shopping, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public Category getCategoryWithSlug(String slug) {
        Category result = new Category();

        for (Category category : categories) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(category.getSlug()) == Integer.parseInt(slug)) {

                return category;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public int getItemsUnderCategory(String slug) {
        int result = 0;
        for (ProductCategory prodcat : prodCats) {
            if (prodcat.getCategory_id() == Integer.parseInt(slug)) {
                result++;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void getItems(String slug) {

        ArrayList<Item> items_to_remove = new ArrayList<Item>();
        for (Item item : items) {
            if(!items_with_slug.contains(item)){
                items_with_slug.add(item);
            }
        }

        for (Item item : items_with_slug) {
              for(Category category : path){
                  if(!item.getCategory().toLowerCase().contains(category.getSlug().toLowerCase())){
                      items_to_remove.add(item);
                  }
              }
        }

        items_with_slug.removeAll(items_to_remove);

        while(items_with_slug.size() != 0){
            items_with_slug.remove(0);
        }

        for (ProductCategory prodcat : prodCats) {
            if (prodcat.getCategory_id() == Integer.parseInt(slug) ) {
                items_with_slug.add(getItemWithId(prodcat.getProduct_id()));
            }
        }

        if(Integer.parseInt(slug) == 0){
            for(Item item : products){
                items_with_slug.add(item);
            }
        }

    }


    public class SequenceComparator implements Comparator<Category>
    {
        public int compare(Category left, Category right) {
            return left.getSequence() - right.getSequence();
        }
    }

    private Item getItemWithId(int product_id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(Item item : items){
            if(item.getId() == product_id){
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    public class ShopItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<Item> items;
        Typeface font, font_light;

        public ShopItemsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Item> items) {
            this.context = c;

            this.items = items;
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf");
            font_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf");
        }



        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return super.isEmpty();
        }



        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (items.size() % 2 == 1)
                return items.size() / 2 + 1;

            return items.size() / 2;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_single_item, null, false);

            LinearLayout llSingleItemCol1 = (LinearLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.llsingle_item_col1);
            ImageView ivImage1 = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivshop_single_image1);
            ImageView ivBannerNew1 = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivshop_single_banner_new1);
            ImageView ivBannerHot1 = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivshop_single_banner_hot1);
            TextView tvName1 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_name1);
            TextView tvBrand1 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_brand1);
            TextView tvPrice1 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_price1);
            TextView tvStock1 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_stock1);
            RatingBar rbRate1 = (RatingBar) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.rbshop_single_rate1);

            LinearLayout llSingleItemCol2 = (LinearLayout) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.llsingle_item_col2);
            ImageView ivImage2 = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivshop_single_image2);
            ImageView ivBannerNew2 = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivshop_single_banner_new2);
            ImageView ivBannerHot2 = (ImageView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivshop_single_banner_hot2);
            TextView tvName2 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_name2);
            TextView tvBrand2 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_brand2);
            TextView tvPrice2 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_price2);
            TextView tvStock2 = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_stock2);
            RatingBar rbRate2 = (RatingBar) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.rbshop_single_rate2);

            tvName1.setTypeface(font);
            tvName2.setTypeface(font);
            tvBrand1.setTypeface(font_light);
            tvBrand2.setTypeface(font_light);
            tvPrice1.setTypeface(font);
            tvPrice2.setTypeface(font);
            llSingleItemCol1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    curr_item = items.get(position * 2 );
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this,
                            SingleProductDrawerActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("item_id", items.get(position * 2).getId());
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
            });

             Picasso.with(context).load(Config.IMAGE_THUMBNAIL+ items.get(position * 2).getFeatured_image()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(ivImage1);

            if (items.get(position * 2).getIsHot()) {
                ivBannerHot1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (items.get(position * 2).getIsNew()) {
                ivBannerNew1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            }

            String name = items.get(position * 2).getName();
            tvName1.setText(name);


            String brand = items.get(position * 2).getShop();
            tvBrand1.setText(brand);

            tvStock1.setText(items.get(position * 2).getStock());
            tvPrice1.setText(String.format("%.2f", items.get(position * 2).getPrice())
                    + context.getResources().getString(R.string.currency));
            rbRate1.setRating(items.get(position * 2).getReview());

            if (position * 2 + 1 != items.size()) {
                name = items.get(position * 2 + 1).getName();
                tvName2.setText(name);


                brand = items.get(position * 2 + 1).getShop();
                tvBrand2.setText(brand);


                tvStock2.setText(items.get(position * 2 + 1).getStock());
                tvPrice2.setText(String.format("%.2f", items.get(position * 2 + 1)
                                .getPrice())
                        +context.getResources().getString(R.string.currency));
                rbRate2.setRating(items.get(position * 2 + 1).getReview());

                Picasso.with(context).load(Config.IMAGE_THUMBNAIL + items.get(position * 2 + 1).getFeatured_image()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(ivImage2);

                if (items.get(position * 2 + 1).getIsHot()) {
                    ivBannerHot2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (items.get(position * 2 + 1).getIsNew()) {
                    ivBannerNew2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                }

                llSingleItemCol2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        curr_item = items.get(position * 2 + 1);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this,
                                SingleProductDrawerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("item_id", items.get(position * 2 + 1)
                                .getId());
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            }

            if (position == items.size() / 2 && items.size() % 2 == 1) {
                llSingleItemCol2.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            }

            return v;
        }
    }

    public class CategoryItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;

        Typeface font, font_light;
        ArrayList<Category> categories;

        public CategoryItemsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Category> categories) {
            this.context = c;
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf");
            font_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf");

            this.categories = categories;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return categories.size() + 2;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_single_category_indented,
                    null, false);

            if (position == 0) {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_categories_header, null,
                        false);

                return v;
            } else if (position == 1) {
                v = inflater
                        .inflate(R.layout.shop_single_category, null, false);
                TextView name = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_category_name);
                name.setText(getCategoryWithSlug(slug).getName());

                return v;
            }

            TextView name = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_category_name);
            name.setText(categories.get(position - 2).getName());
            name.setTypeface(font);

            TextView tvResults = (TextView) v
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvshop_single_category_results);
            tvResults.setText(String.format("%d results",
                    getItemsUnderCategory(categories.get(position - 2)
                            .getSlug())));
            tvResults.setTypeface(font_light);

            return v;
        }
    }

    public class BreadCrumbsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        Context context;

        Typeface font, font_light;
        ArrayList<Category> categories;

        public BreadCrumbsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Category> categories) {
            this.context = c;
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Roman.otf");
            font_light = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTPro-Lt.otf");

            this.categories = categories;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return categories.size() + 1;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_breadcrumb,
                    null, false);

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSingleBreadCrumb_text);

            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(position == 0){
                        slug = "0";
                    }else{  
                        slug = path.get(path.size() - position).getSlug();
                    }
                    updateLists();
                }
            });


            if(position == categories.size() ){
                tvTitle.setTypeface(font);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                params.setMargins(0,0,150,0);
                //tvTitle.setLayoutParams(params);

                ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivSingleBreadCrumb_image_divider);
                image.setLayoutParams(params);

            }else{
                tvTitle.setTypeface(font_light);
            }

            if(position == 0){
                //tvTitle.setTypeface(font);
                tvTitle.setText(getString(R.string.categories));


                return v;
            }

            tvTitle.setText(categories.get(categories.size() - position).getName());

            return v;
        }
    }

    private class GiloAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context context;
        CategoryItemsAdapter adapter;
        ArrayList<Category> categories_with_slug;

        public GiloAdapter(Context c) {
            this.context = c;
        }

        // This is the number of pages -- 5
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public float getPageWidth(int position) {
            if (position == 0)
                return 0.5f;

            return 1.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View v, Object o) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v.equals(o);
        }

        // This is the title of the page that will apppear on the "tab"
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return "";
        }

        // This is where all the magic happen
        public Object instantiateItem(View pager, int position) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop, null, false);

            if (position == 1) {
                lvShopItems = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvShopItems);

                lvShopItems.setAdapter(new ShopItemsAdapter(ShopActivity.this,
                        new ItemsInitiator(ShopActivity.this).getItems()));


            } else {
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_categories, null, false);
                lvShopItems = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvShopItems);

                for (Category cat : categories_with_slug) {
                    Log.d("cat_with_slu", cat.getSlug());
                }

                adapter = new CategoryItemsAdapter(ShopActivity.this,
                        categories_with_slug);

                lvShopItems.setAdapter(adapter);

                lvShopItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int pos, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (pos > 1) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ShopActivity.this,
                                    ShopActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("slug",
                                    categories_with_slug.get(pos - 2).getSlug());
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            // This is very important
            ((ViewPager) pager).addView(v, 0);

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View pager, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) pager).removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View view) {
        }

        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable p, ClassLoader c) {
        }

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View view) {
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: According to your code above, you are using Activity, not AppCompatActivity, so double check that. Also, for the ActionBar/Toolbar what are your XML snippits for your Main Activity as well as the Fragment you are having problems with. Needs more details for a better answer.

Comment: You are declaring " I'm using AppCompatActivity" but you are extending an Activity

Comment: You're right, I edited my initial Post. Thanks for your help.